# Using ModelBuilder to Iterate through rasters and reclassify them

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, modelbuilder, iteration

I'm trying to iterate through a folder which contains many Lidar-Intensity Images as .jpg files.

I want to reclassify them all with the same thresholds (3 classes). I used the "Iterate Raster" and after that the "Reclassify" tool. But the result in the output folder doesn't create a single output raster.

I also tried to use "classify by table" without any success too. It also doesn't work if I try to use other tools like "select by mask" or the raster calculator. When I use these functions on the .jpg files manually (not in the ModelBuilder) it works without any problems.

Here is my model, has anyone suggestions?

[image]

Comment: you should add the software like "arcmap" as tag to your question, since qgis and arcmap/arcgis have a modelbuilder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You iterate raster will output something like "path\raster_name.jpg", meanwhile your raster classification need to save this raster into a Geodatabase. If you run the raster classification manually it will ask you a geodatabase to save the new raster.

So for this you have to add another process to convert your current path without the extension file ".jpg" otherwise the Geodatabase will not accept it.

1- Instert -> model only -> Parse Path

By using parse path you can get some attributes from your file. So you should make variable by parameter and as a parser type you should choose "Name". This will return the name of the image without extension. Than on the end of model you should use the value returned by the parse path not the name returned by iterate raster. Careful in you image name because geodatabase have several restriction of naming files inside it (they should not have special characters).
[image]

Comment: Yes that worked! Thank you really much you saved me hours of work.

Comment: I cant count how many times community saved me :D Good luck